# angularjs (1.3) is refreshing page on form submission with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Whenever I submit the below code, the form reloads the page.  The *alert 'hello'* event is not triggered.  Doesn't angular fire an event.preventDefault() when you don't specify an action for the form?  I'm using the angularjs-rails gem.

**rails controller:**

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  def edit_page
    @response = HTTParty.get("#{Figaro.env.api_url}/1/kites", {})
    @bct_ids = @response["response"]
    gon.bct_ids = @bct_ids
  end


end
```

**angularjs code:**

```
'use strict';

(function(angular) {

  function bctCtr($scope) {
    $scope.bct_ids = gon.bct_ids;
    $scope.addbctIdField = function() {
      $scope.bct_ids.unshift("");
    }
    $scope.removebctIdField = function(index) {
      $scope.bct_ids.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $scope.bctSubmit = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('hello');

    }

  }


  var bctApp = angular.module('bctApp', ['ngResource']);
  bctApp.controller('bctCtr',  bctCtr);

})(angular);
```

**haml(html) code:**

```
%section
  %form{:name => "bctForm", "ng-submit" => "bctSubmit($event)"}
    %table{"ng-app"=>"bctApp", "ng-controller" => "bctCtr"}
      %thead
        %tr
          %th bct ID 
      %tbody
        %tr 
          %td
            %input{:type => "button", :value => "Add bct ID", "ng-click"=>"addbctIdField()"}
            %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Save Changes"}
        %tr{"ng-repeat" => "bct_id in bct_ids track by $index"}  
          %td 
            %input{:type =>"text", :value=>"{{ bct_id }}" }
            %input{:type =>"button", :value=>"Remove", "ng-click"=>"removebctIdField($index)"}
```

Comment: It's in a form and that's the form's default behavior.

Comment: According to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2177, ng-submit is supposed to fire the preventDefault.

Comment: Actually, it's a problem with the haml markup.  The form needs to be nested within the controller.  If I do that, then it works.

Comment: I've never used HAML, but good to hear you figured it out.